# Function to take array of transactions and return the total amount returning wrong number

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner and currently going through an Intro to Coding Course. I keep finding myself overthinking many problems but eventually overcome them - however I am completely stuck on this one which seems pretty simple. Unfortunately the 'lessons' for each segment are approx 2 mins long so not very thorough. I have tried dividing the problem into segments and finding solutions to each part online to no avail.

I have to Define a function, totalTransactions, takes an array of transactions.

totalTransactions should return the total amount spent on all transactions.

Currently I have...

```js
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
    let total = 0;
    for (amount in Object.values(transactions)) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            total += amount;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

This is the example and what the function should return...

```js
let transactions = [
  {
    name: "Tons of glitter",
    amount: 70
  },
  {
    name: "Porcelain Pink Flamingos",
    amount: 92
  },
  {
    name: "Chandelier replacement",
    amount: 10000,
  },
  {
    name: "Dinner at TGIF x6",
    amount: 350
  }
];

lastFridayNight(transactions) // => 10512
```

Comment: What is the value of `transactions`?

Comment: Use reduce array function.

Comment: Do you _need_ to filter out negatives?

Comment: `transactions.reduce((total, obj) => total + obj.amount, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
transactions.forEach(amount => {
     if(amount > 0) {
         total += amount
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for of` instead of `for in` as it will loop throw indexes.

```js
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
    let total = 0;
    for (amount of Object.values(transactions)) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            total += amount;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

console.log(totalTransactions({one: 1, two: 4, three: 2}))
```

But I suggest using `reduce` instead.

```js
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
    return Object.values(transactions).reduce((acc, value) => {
      return value > 0 ? acc += value : acc;
    })
}

console.log(totalTransactions({one: 1, four: 4, two: 2}))
```

Comment: Your reduce version doesn't include the `>0` check...  Also, I think you mean "through", not "throw".

Comment: Thanks, for notifying, I just update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that transactions is an array of transactions like this: `[12, 48, 37, 361, 49]` and that each time represents the sum of each transaction. So you can do:

```
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
   let total = 0;
   for (let i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
        if (transactions[i] > 0)
            total += transactions[i];
   return total;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I don't think I was very clear in my original post, I have updated it with an example and what it should return. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
    let total = 0;
    for (amount of Object.values(transactions)) {
        if (amount > 0) {
            total += amount;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function totalTransactions(transactions) {
    let total=0;
    for (let i = 0;i<transactions.length;i++){
        //console.log(transactions[i].amount);
        total+=transactions[i].amount;
    }
    return total; 
}
```

This works and I have tested it - returns the value 10512